# Is There A Way To Join Meshes and Get Rid Of Excess Mesh?

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, bones, weight-painting

When I made a model of a robot person, I made each part as different mesh: the arms, chest, legs, neck, head, ect. When I finished the model of the robot person, I joined all the parts together with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>.

This poses a problem: By simply joining the meshes, I've left so many useless vertices inside the mesh. This also effects the bones I've added. When I try to move the head, the neck does not move correctly and the top of the neck moves away.

My question is: **Is there a way to join meshes, then get rid of the extra verticies and have the rest of the parts merge nicely so that is is one nice and solid mesh?**

Sorry if that wasn't worded the best. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you add an image, I can better answer your question. There are lots of clever ways to delete unwanted mesh, but the most effective ways involve taking the mesh shape as well as the location of unwanted verticies into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

**If the excess vertices are unconnected:**

In edit mode, hover your cursor over each part of the robot and press <kbd>L</kbd>. This will select all vertices linked to the mesh you want to save. Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to inverse the selection and only select the loose mesh; press <kbd>X</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to then delete.

**If the excess vertices are connected:**

In edit mode, press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all. Then press <kbd>P</kbd> and choose "separate by loose parts". The pieces will detach as you had them before as joined meshes do not necessarily join vertices (this needs to be done manually). You can then delete excess mesh before joining again. Isolating each piece by selecting it and entering local view (<kbd>/</kbd>) will make it easier.

- If you've only just made the mistake of joining the meshes and "undo" isn't helping, look for the .blend2 file. By default, Blender saves a back-up of the last time each file was saved (for these very circumstances). You can also access the .blend2 in Info> Revert (it'll be as if you saved the file before making the mistake).

Comment: When i tried this, it selected each part individually. Hovering over the chest and pressing L selected the chest, the head selected the head, ect. What i want to do is get rid of the inside vertices. EXAMPLE: http://imgur.com/5JM0Thl            The bow is made of 3 different parts. As you can see, the neck and the 3 parts of the bow have faces that are inside the head. How can i fix this to make the model more clean.

Comment: Now that I see your robot, you'll need to use the second method I've listed Be sure to isolate each piece by selecting it and entering local view, so you can see the mesh easier. Let me know if that works.